# Webbased Filemanagment script for my webserver

Tags: php, file, webserver

Hey there,
I have a webserver running apache, php and mysql and I am looking for a really good php-bases script to manage files (upload / download / view) in a certain directory of the website (e.g. domain.com/upload) after user-login. The primary purpose is to be able to quickly access files while not at home. Should also support multiple files-upload via java or something similar.
Thanks!

**Edit:** Found a pretty cool one: http://extplorer.sourceforge.net/
**Edit2** http://www.ajaxplorer.info/wordpress/ :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [eXtplorer](http://extplorer.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: THe only thing about is: Flash Upload isn't working for me :-( Any ideas why? If not, than I will probably be trying ajaxplorer...

Answer (score 0):

[File Thingie](http://www.solitude.dk/filethingie/) is not brand-new any more, but works nicely.

It's free for personal and non-profit use.